# How to pass a value to a variable from React file to node server file

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am a beginner in React and node my question is how to pass the value to a variable from react file to node server file onclick

my code in (React) hello.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class APP extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          value: null,
        };
    }
    
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="greet" >
        
        <div className="hello" onClick={() => this.setState({value: 'Hello'})}>
          <h4>Hello</h4>
        </div>

        <div className="hi" onClick={() => this.setState({value: 'Hi'})}>
            <h4>Hi</h4>
        </div>
    </div>

      
    );
  }
}

export default APP;
```

(Nodejs) server.js file

```
const http = require('http')
const path = require('path')
const express = require('express')
const socketIo = require('socket.io')
const needle = require('needle')
const config = require('dotenv').config()
const TOKEN = process.env.TWITTER_BEARER_TOKEN
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000

const app = express()

const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = socketIo(server)

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../', 'client', 'index.html'))
})



const rules = [onclick value]
```

when on clicking the Hello div in react file the value "hi" should be passed to a const rules in node server file like wise when clicking the hi div the "hi" value should be passed to a variable

Comment: The React app is served up to the browser and the code is executed in the browser’s runtime. This runtime is completely separate from your server which is executed in the node runtime environment. If you want to send information between the two, the most common pattern is to use http requests - are you familiar with this process?

Comment: No i am not familiar with that can you help me with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **Chris** said, you need to make a http request.

You can use Axios library for this. The react app will make that request with one of the methods (ex. POST, GET, PUT, etc.) through axios to an API endpoint which you have to create in Node and the Node will listen to this request which will then forward it to a function and that function will reply with a response or error.

This response or error will then be catched by the axios in the react app as it'll be waiting for it and then when the response is catched, you will have to set that data in the response to your state in your react app so that it reflects in your frontend.

Comment: Thank you both for the answers sure i will go through and do with axios

Answer (score 1):

You can try using FETCH to call the API that you have created in Node.js.
Refer to the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)